# Transforming dataframe to plot interaction effects in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ppl <- data.frame(
  ID = sample(1:50),
  X = rnorm(50, 0.5),
  Y1 = rnorm(50),
  Y2 = rnorm(50, 1)
)
```

Y1 and Y2 are two levels of the condition Y. I want to plot Y against X and see if there's an interaction effect between the two levels of Y. I hope to get an interaction plot like [Work Ethic and Gender as Predictors of GPA](https://ademos.people.uic.edu/Chapter13.html#32_run_your_regression_models), but my data is slightly different in that each individual has two observations, Y1 and Y2.

Any ideas on how to go about transforming the dataframe, and then creating an interaction plot for the two dependent variables in this data set?

Comment: From your question, you have a set of data containing 3 variables - X, Y1, and Y2. However, I am quite confused about which interaction effect you are check. Do you suspect whether Y1 or Y2 having any interaction?

Comment: @Victor19 You're right! However, I realized it's not possible to check for an interaction between two dependent variables. So my question is irrelevant now. Thank you for checking in!